# gzip -9/-6/-1 over mobile connection

Tags: mobile, gzip

Does the -9 have a higher impact on the client's CPU than the default level (6).

And then, what about tests on mobile clients ?

My guesses : 
- use a gzipped version on an Edge connection
- use a minified ungzipped version on a 3G/Wifi connection

With a library such as Cordova, it's quite easy to find which connection type I'm on.

But then, would it be also a good idea to use a different version (gzipped/non gzipped) according to the CPU ?

my guesses :
- non gzipped on an iphone 3GS
- non gzipped on an old cpu for android (sorry, I don't have a list)
- gzipped on an iphone 4GS +

Does this make sense ? Is there an easy way to find out which CPUs are going to have a gain/loss unzipping ratio ?

Comment: Exactly what are you optimizing for? I'm guessing speed of transmission, but there's also battery life and bandwidth caps that could be important.

Comment: speed of transmission as well as CPU use (which is important for a slow device such as an iphone 3G).